# Qt c++ signal slots - necessary to clear signals?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

sorry, I can`t be mor speciic, because I am stuck in a jumble of classes, and several signal/slots.

In my project I use several signal-slots. Now I have the impression that depending on how often I start a routine that emits a signal my slot is run several times.

For the first rum my Slot is run once; In the second run it is run twice.... When I close my program I start again with running it once.

**Is there a need to somehow finish/end/delete a signal after it is sent ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look to the [Qt::UniqueConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) flag.

Comment: Thank you !!! This was it! I had  a private Slot on_pusbButton_cklicked(). In this I had sone Signal-Slots . When I pressed the button the second time I had 2 connections each :-)

Answer (score 3):

You're connecting signals to slots in reaction to events. This causes duplicate connections as the events are repeated. In most cases, this is a bug. Usually you want to set up connections in class constructors, or otherwise when new objects are created and added to your system.

The unique connection will mask the problem, but not solve it - the solution is to move the `connect` statements to locations where they won't be re-executed.

Answer (score 1):

A a signal stays connected, until either the `disconnect()` is used, or the sender or receiver is deleted. 
So each signal/slot pair has to beconnected only once, and then every time the signal is emitted, the slot gets called.